# How to turn off matplotlib inline function and install pygtk?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I got two questions when I was plotting graph in ipython.

1. once, i implement `%matplotlib inline`, I don't know how to switch back to use floating windows.
2. when I search for the method to switch back, people told me to implement 
   `%matplotlib` osx or `%matplotlib`, however, I finally get an error, which is

   > Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.

Can anyone help me, giving me some idea?

p.s. I am using windows 10 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pyGTK. How to do so depends on what you're using to run Python. You could also not use '%matplotlib inline' and then it'll default to whatever is installed on your system.